# How to get starting date from year in python

Tags: python, date

How to get starting date from the year, ex. user select `2013 to 2014` means `1-1-2013 to 31-12-2014` how to get like this.

Comment: Please, be a bit more descriptive about your scenario and explain it in mode detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing it manually:

```
from datetime import date

startdate = date(startyear, 1, 1)
enddate = date(endyear, 12, 31)
```

If `startyear` and `endyear` are not yet integers, convert them first.